# How to call variables from ip.txt file to .sh file?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have list of ip addresses in one txt file which I have named ip.txt

I want to call those ip in my .sh file, I am not sure how to proceed here..

here I did soemthing

```
#!/bin/bash -x
var='ip.txt'
for i in $var; do
echo snmpwalk -v 2c -c rcgoips $i 1.3.6.1.3.83.1.4.5.0
done
```

Please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should make it:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
var='ip.txt'
while read line; do
  echo snmpwalk -v 2c -c rcgoips $line 1.3.6.1.3.83.1.4.5.0
done < $var
```

or using `for` as you do

```
#!/bin/bash -x
var='ip.txt'
for line in $(<$var); do
  echo snmpwalk -v 2c -c rcgoips $line 1.3.6.1.3.83.1.4.5.0
done
```

because the syntax is: `for i in $(<file); do echo $i; done`

Comment: Useless Use Of `cat`... `for line in $(<file)` would be more efficient (or the `while read` version).

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reposne. It is working and I also got the concept.